# Invalid bash script when execute it in Ubuntu Server 18.04 through SSH terminal

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'Provide path to iso file' isofile

read -p 'Provide folder name to extract ISO in' foldername

echo Mounting ISO
sudo mount -o loop /mnt/test/$isofile /mnt/iso
```

in SSH terminal, I try to execute it as

```
$ bash myscript.sh
```

I got

```
Provide folder name to extract ISO in
': not a valid identifier: `foldername
myscript.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
Mounting ISO
: failed to setup loop device for /mnt/MyDisk.
```

I am very new in bash script. What I did wrong ?

Comment: Your script is written in an editor that uses CRLF as line endings. Run `dos2unix <script>` and re run your bash script the same way

Comment: @Inian That should probably be an answer.

Comment: @bitmask: Thanks, we have tons of questions dealing with the similar problem. We'll just wait for the OP to confirm, that indeed was the problem and I will close dup with a much generic question

Comment: @Inian ... or that ...

Comment: Yes, was issue with CRLF, I did it with dos2unix tool. Propose as answer and will accept it